# ReactJS - Test conditional rendering in component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component the uses useEffect to fetch data from a file.
In the component i have a condiiton that only shows the content of the component if we have data.

Now how can a test the conditional part of the content i my test case?

This is what i have right now:

Component:

```
function MunicipalityInfo() {
  const [municipalityData, setMunicipalityData] = useState({})

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try{
      const result = await fetch(XMLFile)
      const data = await result.text();
      const xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(data);
      const res = XMLMapper(xml)
      setMunicipalityData(res)
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
     fetchData();
  }, []);

  return(
    <>
     { municipalityData.units &&
        municipalityData.units.map((city, index) => {
          return (
            <Div key={index} data-testid="municipalityInfo-component" className="mt-5 p-3">
              <HeaderMain data-testid="header-main">{city.City}</HeaderMain>
              <HeaderSub data-testid="header-sub" className="mt-4">{city.venamn}</HeaderSub>
              <BodyText data-testid="body-text">{city.Address}, {city.City}</BodyText>
              <MapLink href={"#"} data-testid="map-link"><i data-testid="map-icon" className="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Show on map</MapLink>
              <LinkList data-testid="link-list">
                <LinkListItem data-testid="list-item-first">
                  <Link href={city.BookingURL} data-testid="link-book-vaccination">Some text</Link>
                </LinkListItem>
              </LinkList>
              <Calendar data={city.unit}/>
            </Div>
          )
        })
      }
      <CitiesSideBar>
        <Sidebar data={municipalityData.cities}/>
      </CitiesSideBar>
    </>
  )
}

export default MunicipalityInfo;
```

And this is my test:

```
describe("<MunicipalityInfo />", () => {
  it("renders without crashing", async  () => {
    const {queryByTestId, findByText, findByTestId} = render(<MunicipalityInfo/>, {})

    expect(queryByTestId("municipalityInfo-component")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(await findByTestId("municipalityInfo-component")).toBeInTheDocument(); <--- this line fails
  })
})
```

And the error of my testcase:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="municipalityInfo-component"]
```

Comment: you should use `queryByTestId` if you're expecting something that might not be in your page

Comment: But im expecting something to be in the document when the useEffect is done

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is trying to test if something shouldn't be in the page...

use the `queryBy`

if you're want it to wait for something... then you want to `await findBy` (or wrap in a waitFor)

here's the docs: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet/

I'm assuming you're mocking the fetch request so it wouldn't be the test problem...

if you're not mocking it... then you probably should mock and return either data or no data to test if it should or not render.

one way to elegantly "avoid" mocking would be by abstracting it in a custom hook:

```js
function useCustomHook(){
  const [municipalityData, setMunicipalityData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(XMLData)
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then(async (data) => {
      let xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(data);
      let result = await XMLMapper(xml)
      setMunicipalityData(await result)
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  return municipalityData;
}
```

```js
function MunicipalityInfo({municipalityData = useCustomHook()}) { ... }
```

then in the test you can simply

```js
render(<MunicipalityInfo municipalityData={'either null or some mocked data'}  />)
```

Comment: I have updated my test case, my last expect that fails looks like this:
expect(await findByTestId("municipalityInfo-component")).toBeInTheDocument();
But it still fails...

Comment: Yes! i can log the data and see it

Comment: it should be working... I would try `console.log(municipalityData)` and see if, in the test it logs something... it should first log the default value, then the fetched value...

Comment: Well, in the browsers console i get first an empty object and after 2 seconds i get the populated object with the data. In the test in only get an empty object.
Now i also get Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 in my test case.

Comment: test environment is something different... are you fetching from your backend? If you are, you should probably mock/spy that.

Comment: I am fetching data form a XML file

Comment: on a unit test, only that part is available... so, you probably have to mock to make it serve the file

Comment: Any tips on how?

Comment: see main answer or see about jest mock/spy

Comment: The issue was the XMLMapper when i use jsonplacholder API i  works and i dont have to mock anything

Comment: when i use the xml the testcase renders the DOM wuthout any populated values, so it seems that the component is not loading nor mock the XML file